# Scrape table in R using rvest

Tags: r

I'm unable to scrape the table in the link mentioned below, i've inspected the source code and noted that the table has class name : tablesaw-sortable

I tested the method below on a wikipedia page and it's able to extract the table, any way to read the particular table?

```
url <- read_html("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KNYC/2015/01/01/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=0")

weather_hourly <- url %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="tablesaw-sortable"]') %>% 
  html_table()
```

Comment: If you want to grab weather underground data, i suggest you try the [rwunderground R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rwunderground) instead.

Comment: @MrFlick they are no longer issuing free API keys

Comment: If you are looking for historical data, I suggest going to NOAA.gov (https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datatools/lcd).  weatherunderground has redesigned their site thus breaking most tools/scripts.

Comment: @Dave2e thanks, found the same information on https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/historic?month=1&year=2015 Scraped data for successive dates using RSelenium package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, something like this should get you pretty close to where you want to be.

```
library("httr")
URL <- "https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/historic?month=8&year=2018"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))

library("XML")
df <- readHTMLTable(temp)
df <- df[[2]]

df
```

Create a small loop if you want to iterate through a bunch of URLs and import data from each.